# how to select from one list to another list

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a list of products. The view which shows the list of products and a selected product works fine. I have a list of categories. The list shows fine. I want to have a select in the list of categories go to a list of products. I will then limit the list of products to the one in that category and show only them.

My problem seems to be creating the Intent in the callback method.

Alert: n00b code follows:

CategoryListFragment.java has:

```
private Callbacks productListCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        Intent productListIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductListActivity.class);
        productListIntent.putExtra("selectedCategory", id);
        startActivity(productListIntent);
    }
};
```

But getApplicationContext() here is not right. Because this inner class does not have access to the Activity?

If I instead declare this with:

```
 private static Callbacks productListCallbacks =
```

Then the startActivity method is not found.

I have tried the things I have seen, like "CategoryListFragment.this" instead of the getApplicationContext() call. Yes, some of this is just random thrashing around. I know.

Is creating an Intent within a Selected callback unusual? With what should I construct the Intent that I want. There is obviously something here which I do not grok....

Comment: since you are into fragment why not using getActivity() instead of getApplicationContext() ?!

Comment: It is not in the fragment. The productListCallbacks ivar is in the fragment. The Intent constructor call is inside the anonymous constructor of the Callbacks instance. This is the pattern that I have seen suggestion over and over and over and over again.